# Wearing sweatpants on shabbos inside

Tags: halacha, shabbat, clothing, home-house

Is it ok for me to wear my sweatpants and tee-shirt in the house on Shabbos or do I have to stay in my Shabbos clothing even when I'm hanging out in my apartment?

Comment: Why would you think you can't wear normal clothing on Shabbos?

Comment: What if the sweatpants are your Shabbat clothing?

Comment: According to the Ben Ish Chai one should wear their shabbas clothes until they finish melava malka and then they can switch into weekday clothing ,so kal chomer a regular meal one needs their shabbas clothing,now whats considered shabbas clothing is a seprate issue

Comment: @DoubleAA. They're not. If they were in wouldn't have asked the question. I'm discussing removing my skirt and blouse and putting on my sweatpants and tee-shirt.

Comment: Should you be just "hanging out" on Shabbos, or at any other time?

Comment: @ZevSpitz. Hanging out with the kids. Playing UNO. Saying Tehillim. What's wrong? Hanging out is not the problem. It's what you do when you hang out that could be problematic.

Comment: As always, don't rely on this site for practical halacha. Ask your rabbi.